# Uploading by folder

Tags: php, drupal, module

I have a system in place that uses the multiupload module to upload hundreds of files at once. I was told to try and make it possible to upload all the contents of a folder this way, so actually **selecting a folder to upload all the proper files contained in it.**
I'm pretty new to Drupal in general and I tried searching for a possible solution to that but most answers I found were referencing the folder to upload to.
I'm not necessarily looking for a solution but a push in the right direction would help as well :)

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Hey the actual code might be long

following logic can help you

1: - create a form to upload a zip or rar
2: - after successfully upload of zip or rar extract it

code sample for extracting zip given below

```
<?php
$zip = zip_open("zip.zip");
if ($zip) {
  while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
    $fp = fopen("zip/".zip_entry_name($zip_entry), "w");
    if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
      $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
      fwrite($fp,"$buf");
      zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
      fclose($fp);
    }
  }
  zip_close($zip);
}
?>
```

in above code you have to add logic to add file in Database , i.e. read folder recursively than make entry in database